# Should I code binary factor variables as zero or one for decision tree?

Tags: r, decision-tree

I'm building a decision tree and I have a bunch of binary variables that I'm coding as factors.

They each have two levels where the first level is "has attribute" and the second level is "does not have attribute"

And the attribute is replaced with the name of the column, like "has blue rose pedals"

This is the model I'm applying my data with, with iris as the example code

```
library(rpart)
model <- rpart(Species ~., data = iris)
par(xpd = NA) 
plot(model)
text(model, digits = 3)
```

The question I have is whether I should code binary factor variables as zero or one?

Comment: Typical convention is to code True values with `1` and False values with `0`, if that was the question.

Comment: Coding True with 1 is practical for combining logical and arithmetic operations: `(a == True)*2 + (a == False)*3`.

Comment: You normally code factors as 0 (not having) 1 (having) because if you perform a linear regression, it is easier to interpret the coefficients. Positive means positively correlation with the presence of the factor.

Comment: In my tibble, should I code them as a factor with levels 1 and 0 or numeric?

Comment: In the example you have provided ```rpart(Species ~ .,data=iris)``` the only factor is in the dependent variable  ```Species```so it does not matter that much, as long as you remember what is the rationale for the levels of the factors. Also, note that you need to use method = "poisson" to do a classification

Comment: Can you speak more to using method "poisson" It works when I don't use that method

Comment: in your case, if you are using rpart, it doesn't matter.. because rpart does not do coefficients like linear regression

Comment: where are your factors? dependent or independent variables?

Comment: I have factors in my dependent and independent variables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222669/discussion-between-stupidwolf-and-cauder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical convention is to code `True` values with `1` and `False` values with `0`.

Using this mapping it is possible to combine logical and arithmetic operations in the following way:

```
result <- (a == TRUE)*2 + (a == FALSE)*3
```